# Select distinct tuples in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time reasoning about a problem:

Given this table:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | sibling_id |
+------+------------+
|    1 |       NULL |
|    2 |          3 |
|    3 |          2 |
|    4 |          5 |
|    5 |          4 |
+------+------------+
```

If I choose `ids` `(1,2,3,5)`, I'd like to only get `(1,2,4)`, because `3 points to 2`, and `2 points to 3`, so I only want one of both.

Expected output:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | sibling_id |
+------+------------+
|    1 |       NULL |
|    2 |          3 |
|    4 |          5 |
+------+------------+
```

How could I do that with mysql (5.7) ?

**Solution** :

`select distinct least(id, coalesce(sibling, id)) from test where id in (1,2,3,5);`

Thanks everyone !

Comment: shouldn't you get (1,2,4) ?

Comment: Why `5`, since that points to `4`? Shouldn't you receive `1,2,4`?

Comment: No because 4 is not in my list of chosen ids (which is 1, 2, 3, 5)

Comment: Actually you're right, (1, 2, 4) would work too. Even if 4 was not in the initial list :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure, that the tuples are always the same (meaning for example always being (2,3) and not (3,2)). You can do so by always putting the smaller value in the front and the greater value at the end of the tuple. Use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` for it.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
LEAST(id, sibling_id), GREATEST(id, sibling_id)
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,5);
```

Comment: I ended up with this query :
`select distinct least(id, coalesce(sibling, id)) from test where id in (1,2,3,5);`

Answer (score -2):

You may use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(id, sibling_id), GREATEST(id, sibling_id) FROM table 
WHERE sibling_id NOT IN(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table )
```

Comment: Wouldn't that skip 2,3,4,5 ?